# Unclear CORS filter in Play

Tags: reactjs, scala, playframework, fetch, silhouette

I have app in Play. My application.conf file is:

```
include "silhouette.conf"

play.modules.enabled += "modules.SilhouetteModule"


play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["."]
}

play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = null
}
```

So, we can see that all sources should go.

My front-end fetch request looks like this (in react app):

```
export function signIn(email, password) {
    const host = "http://localhost:9000/"
    const route = "signIn";
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
        credentials: 'include',      
    };
    return fetch(host + route, requestOptions)
}
```

Chrome shows this:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/signIn' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Yes, I tried to use `'no-cors'` but it still doesn't work ;) It's very unclear, and I don't know how it works and how to configure it.

Comment: I don't know about the play or scala but I know about this, please add `origin: true` or `origin: ['http://localhost:3000']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Play adds CSRF filter as default. After adding `+nocsrf` in routes file everything works. It's quite odd and unclear.

```
# Authentication
+nocsrf
POST        /signUp                                   controllers.SignUpController.signUp
+nocsrf
POST        /signIn                                   controllers.SignInController.signIn
+nocsrf
POST        /signOut                                  controllers.SignInController.signOut
```

Comment: You solved your problem by your self, nice

Comment: Of course I appreciate your efforts and I gave you point for your answer :) Anyway, Play is very unclear and there's no community.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the thing, I get from the play framwork documentation

```
play.filters.cors {
  pathPrefixes = ["/some/path", ...]
  allowedOrigins = ["http://www.example.com", ...] <-- Add your localhost url here
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

Doc: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/CorsFilter

Comment: It doesn't work I studied Play documentation many times :/